# Flat resolutions of DG-schemes

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-algebraic-geometry

Recall that a DG-scheme is a pair $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$,
where $(X,\mathcal{O}^0_X)$ is a scheme, $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of commutative DG-algebras over $(X,\mathcal{O}^0_X)$, and each $\mathcal{O}^i_X$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}^0_X$-module.

I would like to know if in this generality (without assuming things like $X$ being quasi-projective over a field of characteristic zero), is it known that maps of DG-schemes have flat resolutions?

That is, given a map $f:X \to Y$ of DG-schemes, can it be factored as $X \to \tilde{X} \to Y$, such that $X \to \tilde{X}$ is a quasi-isomorphism, and $\tilde{X} \to Y$ is K-flat?

Also, are there any natural assumptions that will make $\tilde{X}$ not too big? (for instance, made of coherent $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}^0$-modules?)

My motivation is to understand in general the derived fiber product $X\times^R_Y Z$, where $X,Y,Z$ are (DG-)schemes.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a remark in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212226v1.pdf alludes to a future paper (citation [3], part IV in the series) which would probably contain what you're looking for.  It doesn't seem like it's been published yet but you could probably ask him.